# Qt4 - The same connect for different progressBar, emit make the same value for each

Tags: qt4, progress-bar

I have multiple `QProgressBar*` which I connect like follow :

```
void MainWindow::newProgressBar()
{
    QProgressBar *progressBar = new QProgressBar();

    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(changeProgressBarValue(int)), progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));

    emit changeProgressBarValue((_table->item(newRow, 3)->text().toDouble() - _table->item(newRow, 2)->text().toDouble()) / _table->item(newRow, 3)->text().toDouble() * 100);
}
```

The problem is that if I `emit changeProgressBarValue(52)`, all the progressBars will take the value 52.

I don't know how many progress bar there will be. It could be zero or a hundred.

How can I make a specific "listener / connect" for each ?
I don't want to create a signal for each, there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a specific QProgressBar that you want to set the value of then you could simply call:

```
progressBar->setValue(52)
```

Comment: Oh well, didn't know I could call a slot that way. But that doesn't solve my problem, because I create the progressBars in a function and I don't save their pointers. Because I don't know how many there are. There could be none or a hundred. Post Edit

Comment: How do you plan to identify which of the progress bars you want to set the value of?

Comment: That's the point.^^ Until now, the best idea I had was to create a ProgressBar list. So I can remember which one I want to modify the value.

Comment: I was more asking how you determine which progress bar to update, not how you access the variable representing that progress bar.  You'll need to store some kind of reference for each progress bar, so a list of the progress bars you have created would be one method.

Comment: Oh but I'm dumb ! I think I can access to this progressBars even if I don't save them in a list. I have access to their container, so I can "find" the good one.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure how you plan to identify them, but it's good you have a plan!  When you are doing `new QProgressBar()` you need to give a parent (or add it to a layout or something) otherwise you are going to leak memory.

Comment: It's in a TableWidget. It's not working yet, but I'm on it.^^ I'm trying to change the `emit changeProgressBarValue(...)` to something like `reinterpret_cast<QProgressBar*>(_table->cellWidget(row, 4))->setValue(...);`